# How to run sed -i in sql

Tags: sql

I downloaded a sql file of english dictionary. It said The syntax in the wordnet20 has a deprecated TYPE=* in the .sql file. Run `sed -i 's/TYPE=/ENGINE=/g' wordnet20-from-prolog-all-3.sql` to replace the deprecated syntax before running it against a 5.0+ version of MySQL –
How can I run it

Comment: You need to run it in your terminal (assuming a unix-like operating system).

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is the UNIX (and now Linux) "stream editor," allowing you to make changes to text input from the command line.  What it does best is what's suggested here, searching and replacing.

The instructions are telling you to change all instances of `TYPE=` to `ENGINE=`...which, honestly, they should have just said and used `sed -i` (the option says to make the changes to the file on disk, instead of printing the results) as an *example* of how to do that.

I should add that most GUI editors are going to need a *lot* of memory to get through a large file, so `sed` is going to be a far better option.  You can run Linux on a virtual machine or install Linux-like utilities for your system to get it.